# Migration SQL managed Instance DB to another tenant SQL MI

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am stuck with a SQL migration between 2 tenants. Any help will be really appreciated.

There is one SQL Server managed instance TDE enabled is sitting in one tenant and we have to move the same to a different tenant.

- Since the TDE is enabled with platform managed key we can't take direct backup (`.bak`)
- I have tried going with Data Tier extract (`.bacpac`) but due to database relationship in views making it fail
- Data Tier export (`.dacpac`) is working for schema but failing with data

We can't create tunnel between 2 databases because of CIDR overlap and being it SQL Server MI so native replication is not an option.

Looking forward for any suggestion or solutions.

---

There is no option to disable TDE either It will be on Platform managed key or Customer Managed key.

Comment: Disable TDE, move the instance, create new key and re-enable TDE?

Comment: If you change it to BYOK (as opposed to Platform managed), then you *can* take a copy_only backup to a blob. See https://bradleyschacht.com/bring-your-own-key-to-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-tde/

Comment: Alternatively, it looks like SQL 2022 will allow for a backup from Managed Instance to an On-Prem version of SQL Server, so that may be a path for you.